useSWRInfinite not returning complete data in first attempt
I am using useSWRInfinite to fetch paginated data. The original API response contains 75 entries, pagination info and status. The data returned from useSWRInfinite contains only 5 data entries at first and then after a second or so it returns complete data. I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Why is it not returning all the data in first attempt even though the API is returning correct response.
function useInfinitePagination<K, T>(
  queryParams: K,
  initialData: PaginatedData<T>,
  url: string,
  config: SWRConfiguration = {},
) {
  const [paginatedData, setPaginatedData] = useState<T[]>(initialData.data);
  const [paginationInfo, _setPaginationInfo] = useState(
    initialData.paginationInfo
  );

  const { data, error, isValidating, mutate, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
    (index) => `${url}?${qs.stringify({ ...queryParams, page: index + 1 })}`,
    fetcher,
    { initialData: initialData.data, initialSize: 1, ...config }
  );
console.log("data", data)
  useEffect(() => {
    setSize(1);
  }, [JSON.stringify(queryParams)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!data?.[0]?.data) {
      _setPaginationInfo(data?.[0]?.paginationInfo);
      let flattenData = data?.map((item: any) => {
        return item.data;
      });
      flattenData = [].concat.apply([], flattenData || []);
      setPaginatedData(flattenData.filter(Boolean));
    }
  }, [data]);
console.log("hook", paginatedData)
  function hasMore() {
    return paginationInfo && size < paginationInfo.totalPages;
  }

  function resetPage() {
    setSize(1);
  }

  function loadMore() {
    if (hasMore() && !isValidating) {
      setSize(size + 1);
    }
  }

  return {
    loadMore,
    hasMore,
    paginatedData,
    error,
    isValidating,
    mutate,
    size,
    setSize,
    resetPage,
    paginationInfo,
  };
}

I have tried to debug the issue but couldn't figure out the problem.
